# Initializing object with return value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following code and I am trying to use the return value of a function to initialize a property of an object.

```
$scope.data = {
  trackingItemStatus: {
    options: SPListUtility.GetChoiceOptionsJson(),
    defaultOption: {value: 'Active', text: 'Active'}
  }
}
```

Right before returning from my service above I log the variable to be returned and it is coming back as follows so I know it should be working:

```
[{"text":"Active","value":"Active"},{"text":"Closed","value":"Active"},{"text":"On-Hold","value":"On-Hold"},{"text":"Resolved","value":"Resolved"}]
```

I feel like this should be simple. I just want to assign the return value of my function to data.item.options but it won't work just keeps coming back empty. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Post the *real* code. What you're doing should work, unless you're doing something wrong. We can't tell however unless the real code is posted. Also, if you're getting errors in the console, that would be extremely useful too.

Comment: Maybe `someFuncThatReturnsArray()` returns a Promise, and you are testing it for the resolved value?

Comment: That was the problem, it was returning a promise, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that the call to `SPListUtility.GetChoiceOptionsJson()` returns a promise, in which case you must resolve the returned value, like so:

```
SPListUtility.GetChoiceOptionsJson().then(function (value) {
  $scope.data = {
    trackingItemStatus: {
      options: value,
      defaultOption: {value: 'Active', text: 'Active'}
    }
  };
});
```